# If a 'draught' is a liquid, why is this book title "Draughts and Potions"?

Tags: vocabulary

> COURSE BOOKS 
>       All students should have a copy of each of the following: 
>       The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1) by Miranda Goshawk 
>       A History of Magic by Bathilda Bagshot 
>       Magical Theory by Adalbert Waffling 
>       A Beginners' Guide to Transfiguration by Emetic Switch 
>       One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi by Phyllida Spore 
>       Magical ***Draughts and Potions*** by Arsenius Jigger 
>       Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them by Newt Scamander 
>       The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection by Quentin Trimble 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

OALD says: [draught](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/draught), one continuous action of swallowing liquid; [potion](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/potion), a drink of medicine or poison; a liquid with magic powers. But it also has this meaning for draught: medicine in a liquid form. So I’m wondering what ‘draught’ means. Which one or what else is for it?

Comment: Indeed, they mean the same. I think why "draughts" and "potions" are said separately is because some potions take the name "potion" as their name's end and some potions take "draught" at their name's end. So, there may be liquids, "X draught" and "Y draught" and "A potion" and "B potion". To include all kind of liquids, the words "draught" and "potion" are differently used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Draught](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/draught?q=draught) (US: Draft) **literary** or archaic - a quantity of a liquid with medicinal properties: a sleeping draught.

Commonly used in literature relating to witches' brews.

A **draught** was generally assigned to the purpose of "spells" (e.g. sleep, inhibition, etc.) or a form of control of the recipient.

Whereas **potions** were generally intended to bring harm or death to the recipient. The imagery often involves witches brewing over a large cauldron and using unusual ingredients (e.g. the eye of a newt, blood from some exotic animal, etc.).

Comment: If both are liquid medicine, what's the difference between the two? Why the title reiterates liquid, liquid?

Comment: @Listenever Just for poetic effect.

Comment: @Listenever - I think the difference between a _draught_ and a _potion_ in this context is left up to the imagination of the reader. But it wouldn't be unlike a bar that boasts "We serve over 30 different **beers and ales**: many customers would be fine with just "over 30 different beers," but connoisseurs and experts would understand and appreciate the difference.